# Why is there no operator ~= in C++?

Tags: c++, syntax, operators, language-lawyer, language-design

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int a = 0;
    unsigned int b = 0;

    a ^= b; // ok
    a |= b; // ok
    a &= b; // ok
    a = ~b; // ok
    a ~= b; // error : expected ';' after expression
}
```

`^=`, `|=`, and `&=` are all legal.

Why isn't `~=` legal in C++?

Comment: Permission to switch "standards" for "language-lawyer"?

Comment: Is defining an `bool operator~=()` legal?

Comment: And why is this question being downvoted? It's well-written, with a code snippet which necessarily doesn't compile, and nobody has found a duplicate yet.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Depending on how you read this, the question may be hard to answer. The obvious answer (which I gave) may not be what the OP is after; the real question may be "why wasn't the language designed differently", which is *really hard* to answer.

Comment: You might be correct, I've just upvoted your answer. But methinks I and @MaximEgorushkin answered it in the obvious way.

Comment: @rsp: Love the dupe. Looks like I'm good at answering this question ;-) Even my notation is consistent. I'm a constant cat.

Comment: @Bathsheba Asking why there is not a meaningless operator in C++ is like asking why there is not a builtin function that makes coffee. It can be well written, IMHO it's still a useless question.

Comment: It's more to do with *why* it's meaningless. My new compiler makes me a cup of coffee when I write `i = i++;`. The previous one used to eat my cat.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Maxim's point certainly shows a plausible reason for this design and how the status quo is consistent, but note that the language  also contains unary operators that modify their operands (e.g. `++`), so it's not entirely clear a priori why there shouldn't be a modifying variant of NOT (either kind). It's just not there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`~` is only ever a *unary* operator.

The contraction of `a = a @ b` to `a @= b` for an arbitrary operator `@` only makes sense if it takes two arguments; i.e. if `@` is a *binary* operator.

Answer (score 11):

Because `~` is an *unary* operator, not *binary*.

The short form `op=` applies to binary operators only, when the first operand is the destination.

Comment: Still, it would be pretty sweet to overload it as a binary. For example: if (bin ~= group) group.add(bin);

Answer (score 1):

> Why isn't `~=` legal in C++?

That's because C++ does not contain an `~=` operator; `~=` are just two separate tokens.

As for why C++ wasn't designed that way, you'd have to ask the designer, but I think it's safe to say that it's because C++ was based on C originally and has the same operators as C, with only a few new operators added for the new language features (i.e. `::` and `->*`).

So you should probably ask this question again for C.

Answer (score 0):

Because the "operator assignments"  (like `+=`, `^=`) are based on the original operation having two operands.

For example, `a + b` has two operands of `+`,  and `a += b` gives the same net effect as `a = a + b`.

Operator `~` is a unary operator i.e. it accepts one operand.   So `a = ~b` makes sense, but `a = a~b` does not.    Since `a = a~b` doesn't make sense, neither does `a ~= b`.